# Responsive ul image list not breaking to new line

Tags: java, jar, ftp, portfolio

On the portfolio section of my site I have a ul of image screenshots of sites I have made. The main div is set to `min-width: 700px` and views fine in a web browsers. However on mobile/tablet the last img in the ul does not move to a new line and is instead cut off.

Can someone please advise on the best css rule to apply or if I should restructure the ul completely.

View the issue here: [portfolio](http://www.gregorydanelian.comule.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the white-space: nowrap property for #container1, #container2, #container3, #container4.

The images do not move to the next line because of nowrap.